# Why does TypeScript throw an error when I recurrsively refer to an interface

Tags: typescript, recursion, interface

The code is as follows ([TS Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20interface%20IConversionData%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bindex%3A%20string%5D%3A%20IConversionData%20%7C%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20conversionData%3A%20IConversionData%20%3D%20%7B%20header%3A%20%7B%7D%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AconversionData.header%5B%229106%22%5D%20%3D%20%224%22%3B%0D%0AconversionData.header%5B%229132%22%5D%20%3D%20%221%22%3B%0D%0AconversionData.header.myChild2%5B%22abc%22%5D%20%3D%20%221%22%3B)):

```
interface IConversionData {
    [index: string]: IConversionData | string;
}

const conversionData: IConversionData = { header: {}}

conversionData.header["9106"] = "4";
conversionData.header["9132"] = "1";
conversionData.header.myChild2["abc"] = "1"; //Property 'myChild2' does not exist on type 'string | IConversionData'. Property 'myChild2' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

I know that [recursive interface types are possible in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3496#issuecomment-128553540) but this still throws an error. Why?

Comment: Recursive interfaces are not the problem, header will be of type IConversionData | string, so myChild2 is not defined on that ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with recursion:

```
(conversionData.header) is of type IConversionData | string
```

So it is telling you that you can't access to `myChild2`, because one of the options is `string` and `string` lacks of `myChild2`.

By the way, your example is easily fixable by doing:

```
export interface IConversionData {
    [index: string]: IConversionData | string;
}

const conversionData: IConversionData = { header: {}}

conversionData.header["9106"] = "4";
conversionData.header["9132"] = "1";
conversionData.header["myChild2"] = {abc: "1"};
```

Comment: Can you do this without casting?